# Get a particular day from a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to get a day from a date range?

**For example:-** If say suppose I have date range as 22/June/2014 to 28/June/2014 then I want to get the Monday of this date range ie, 23/June/2014 as Monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got this one working for me.

```
declare @DateFrom DateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '22/06/2014', 103) 
declare @DateTo DateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, '28/06/2014', 103) 
;WITH CTE(dt) 
AS 
( 
Select @DateFrom 
Union All 
Select DATEADD(d,1,dt)FROM CTE 
Where dt<@DateTo 
) 

select *,'Monday' as [Day] from cte where datename(dw,dt) = 'Monday'
```

Comment: Just put this after the cte `select * from cte where datename(dw,dt) = 'Monday'`. Also I think it's worth noting if you have to do calculations like this all the time. You may want to consider building a calendar table. In it you can hold things like day of week, quarter, etc.

Comment: @JChao:- Thanks for optimizing it.!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select date  
from table 
where date between range1 and range2 
and datename(mm,date) = 'Monday'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MondayAfterRangeStart
FROM table
     CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT DATEADD(DAY, ((DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, RangeStart) - 1)  / 7) * 7 + 7, 0) AS MondayAfterRangeStart
     ) AS CA1 
WHERE MondayAfterRangeStart <= RangeEnd
```